# Is there a list ID for "ALL" in Wunderlist?

Tags: zapier, wunderlist

I'm trying to make a zap in zapier that will work on all new tasks regardless of what list they go in.  Is there a way to reference "ALL" as a list ID so I can capture each new task regardless of what list it's in?

Comment: I don't think is possible - Just duplicate the zap and change the list ID so it works with each list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no such option ("ALL" as id) in Wunderlist, but there is a simple way to detect any change in Wunderlist (so tasks are included).
Just check the `revision` number of [`root`](https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/endpoints/root) object with this command:

```
GET a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/root
```

and if it was changed then check [revisions](https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/concepts/revisions) of descendants of the root objects

Comment: Not really actually doing any api programming sorry, just writing in iPaaS.